# Within iOS, what are the differences between an MVC "View Controller" and and an MVVM "ViewModel"?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, mvvm

Within Apple's **iOS**, what are the differences between an MVC "View Controller" and and an MVVM "ViewModel"? I think conceptually there is little difference. In practical terms they appear different. I'd like to see a list of both conceptual and practical differences.

Answer (score 0):

It is a detailed implementation for us we use MVVM. we have Web API provide VM "View Model" form the Backend side. on the FrontEnd the app code map "View Modle" to model in the APP and show data in UI.